# While Loop help. Running loop twice

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to code a simple random word generator and I am having issues with the while loop. When I run the code it asks the user for a strong or weak password. Strong will generate 14 random characters and weak will combine two words from a list. After choosing a password it will ask if you another password and if yes it will ask the question again. But when I run it once it asks for another password but it asks choose a strong/weak 2 times instead of asking for another password.

```
def randpasswd(length, chars=None):
    if chars == None:
        chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%¨&*()_+/*\\|<>;:"

        password = ""
        for i in range(length):
            password += random.choice(chars)
    return password
def choosing():
    choose = input("Choose strong or weak password: ")
    a = ["password", "crash", "intel", "working"]

    if choose == "strong":
        print(randpasswd(14))
    if choose == "weak":
        print(''.join(random.choices(a, k=2)))
while True:
    choosing()
    done = input("Do you want another password? ")
    if done == "yes":
        choosing()
    elif done == "no":
        print("password is set")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if done == "yes":
    choosing()
```

with

```
if done == "yes":
    continue
```

so instead of

1. `choosing()` being run,
2. followed by the `elif` branch that would not be taken (since the other branch was taken),
3. followed by the loop starting over,

control just skips back to the start of the `while True` loop, where `choosing()` will be run anyway. (`pass` would do here too instead of `continue`, but the latter is more explicit.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current `while` loop with this:

```
want_another = "yes"
while want_another != "no":
    if want_another == "yes":
        choosing()
    want_another = input("Do you want another password? ")
print("password is set")
```

Right now, `done` is very badly named, since done is "no" when you are done and "yes" when you are not done.